# How to calculate cross validation error for ridge regression model?

Tags: r, machine-learning, regression, cross-validation

I am trying to fit a `ridge` [regression](/questions/tagged/regression) model on the [white wine dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Wine+Quality). I want to use the entire dataset for training and use 10 fold CV for calculating the test error rate. Thats the main question - how to calculate CV test error for a ridge regressed logistic model. **I calculated the best value of `lambda` (also using `CV`), and now I want to find the `CV` test error rate.** Currently, my code for calculating the said CV test error is -

```
cost1 <- function(good, pi=0) mean(abs(good-pi) > 0.5)
ridge.model <- glmnet(x, y, alpha = 0, family = "binomial", lambda = bestlam)
ridge.model$beta # all coefficients for the variables
ridge.model.cv.err<- cv.glm(winedata,ridge.model,cost1, K=10)
ridge.model.cv.err$delta
```

This gives the following error -

> Error in cbind2(1, newx) %*% nbeta : not-yet-implemented method for  %*%

**Any ideas what could be causing this error?**

---

It was [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61025542/why-cant-i-use-cv-glm-on-the-output-of-bestglm?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment107970414_61029086) that I should use `cv.glmnet` instead. However, it doesn't seem like it accepts the model type (that would be logistic here) as input, plus it needs a list of lambda values as input, whereas I just have one best lambda value that I got as mentioned above. So running the code -

```
ridge.model.cv.err<- cv.glmnet(x,y, lambda = bestlam, cost1, K=10)
```

gives the error - `Error in cv.glmnet(x, y, lambda = bestlam, cost1, K = 10) : Need more than one value of lambda for cv.glmnet`

The data were processed as -

```
winedata <- read.delim("winequality-white.csv", sep = ';')
winedata$quality[winedata$quality< 7] <- "0" #recode
winedata$quality[winedata$quality>=7] <- "1" #recode
winedata$quality <- factor(winedata$quality)# Convert the column to a factor
names(winedata)[names(winedata) == "quality"] <- "good"      #rename 'quality' to 'good'
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Sounds like Your original data frame has a factor (categorical) variable among the predictor variables. When you use model.matrix it does something sensible with this variable; if you just pass it directly to predict, it doesn't know what to do. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35437411/error-in-predict-glmnet-function-in-r